# CSS variable width floating divs - prevent 2nd div wrapping / line-breaking below 1st div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-float

I have a div with a variable sized thumbnail image to the left and another div to the right with info that I'd like keep aligned to the right without wrapping below the image div (leaving white space below the image).

I've tried display: inline-block to prevent the info div wrapping below the image, but if the info is too wide it will cause the info div to line-break below the image div (leaving white space to the right of the image).

All the solutions I've found rely on set widths for the divs, but in my case both widths can be variable widths.

I'm using bootstrap, but can't use set cols on my divs in this case due to the different possible thumbnail image widths.

Here's my problem when using inline-block:
**http://plnkr.co/edit/wfbQ7He3lM5Lz2amMiCK?p=preview**

Any ideas?

Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="myapp-image pull-left">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/195/133" alt="Kittens">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="myapp-info pull-left">
            <p>
                <strong>Some long text that will cause div to drop below thumbnail image:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo civibus fuisset laboramus ut, veri ancillae contentiones id vix, duo an dolor suscipit. Omnis possit perfecto per ex, inimicus maluisset at eum. Vel et suas qualisque. Ut pri homero antiopam omittantur, alia congue principes mei no.
                Oratio indoctum disputationi usu at. Pro blandit moderatius ne. Ignota aperiam adolescens est in, per adolescens accommodare at. Ne vitae nonumes nusquam pri, ex has suas putent admodum. Et mel duis labitur, noluisse invenire ex sed, qui case justo scripserit ne.
                Ei nam ferri partiendo, est at dicunt docendi. Delectus concludaturque nec id. Vim at saepe dicam dicant. Mea alii saperet theophrastus eu. Pro eu odio idque praesent.
                Eos at quidam iracundia interpretaris, his tale verear iuvaret ne. Epicuri reformidans ius ne, pro no quem pertinax eloquentiam. Mazim quando eos cu. Te cum insolens cotidieque. Sed deserunt mediocrem no, ei legere ancillae suscipiantur nec, everti suscipit reprimique et pro. Paulo detracto vituperata id mea. Cu mel labore percipitur, labores reformidans necessitatibus cu duo.
                Illum nominavi corrumpit eum ne. His an nonumy singulis, quo legere semper instructior ne. Sint alienum laboramus vim ex, splendide vituperatoribus ea eos. Malis dictas regione an usu. At quo habeo appareat laboramus, mel labores consequuntur ei, at omnis tempor tritani cum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myapp-image
{
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.mapapp-info
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to achieve this by just manipulating CSS? as far as I know, it's not possible in the specified condition that image area is supposed to be flexible and the rest of the bottom area should also be empty, keeping the info area relatively flexible.

Comment: @hina10531 - I was hoping to achieve this with just CSS. I figured some CSS guru out there might no a hack to get around the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no one who could do this by just manipulating pure css or html with no fixed value ( at lease min-* attributes ) on layout-layer elements. This idea just doesn't make sense unfortunately. You said that the only solution is to set fixed width on div? that's the final, only one solution. If you want some scripts for this and if you are okay with that, then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/3/4/1393940776876/Dahlia-Karma-Choc-009.jpg" alt="Kittens">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <p>
        <strong>Some long text that will cause div to drop below thumbnail image:</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quo civibus fuisset laboramus ut, veri ancillae contentiones id vix, duo an dolor suscipit. Omnis possit perfecto per ex, inimicus
        maluisset at eum. Vel et suas qualisque. Ut pri homero antiopam omittantur, alia congue principes mei no. Oratio indoctum disputationi usu at. Pro blandit moderatius ne. Ignota aperiam adolescens est in, per adolescens accommodare at. Ne vitae
        nonumes nusquam pri, ex has suas putent admodum. Et mel duis labitur, noluisse invenire ex sed, qui case justo scripserit ne. Ei nam ferri partiendo, est at dicunt docendi. Delectus concludaturque nec id. Vim at saepe dicam dicant. Mea alii
        saperet theophrastus eu. Pro eu odio idque praesent. Eos at quidam iracundia interpretaris, his tale verear iuvaret ne. Epicuri reformidans ius ne, pro no quem pertinax eloquentiam. Mazim quando eos cu. Te cum insolens cotidieque. Sed deserunt
        mediocrem no, ei legere ancillae suscipiantur nec, everti suscipit reprimique et pro. Paulo detracto vituperata id mea. Cu mel labore percipitur, labores reformidans necessitatibus cu duo. Illum nominavi corrumpit eum ne. His an nonumy singulis,
        quo legere semper instructior ne. Sint alienum laboramus vim ex, splendide vituperatoribus ea eos. Malis dictas regione an usu. At quo habeo appareat laboramus, mel labores consequuntur ei, at omnis tempor tritani cum.

    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - much appreciated. Ideally I'd like it the image side of things not to resize as it's just a small thumbnail image (of variable size).